# Export table data to excel file

Tags: powerbi

A client of mine is asking me to export the data from a table or matrix visualization to an excel file for custom reports.

I checked out an excel plugin but couldnt make it work.

Can this be made? Is it one of the premium features only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. You can do it like this from Power Bi.

[image]

Another approach is if he has an account to power bi that has access to the report he can use an excel plugin to connect to the tabular model.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/publisher-for-excel

Comment: The excel plugin is to connect from excel to a power bi service dataset. If you want to export data from a power bi, it is not necessary the plugin. You can export data from any visualization. I recommend exporting from tables or matrix (because you can check the data you are exporting)